# 3 finger gripper model for moveit/gazebo?

Tags: ros, gazebo, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, my idea is to work with a 3D Model of the 3 finger gripper hand and with ROS change its state (close/opening). I know this is quite basic stuff to do, but I just want to try it out in order to advance to other thing. The problem is I can't find a model out there.

Can anyone tell me if there is a urdf model of the hand that I can use so I can make it subscribe to a certain topic. I've found one but I couldn't use it since I believe some files were missing or wrong.

---

Edit: I've managed to display the hand in gazebo but how do you use that plugin? It comes with the "RDS" or can I use it in ROS? I'm asking this because I want to be able to change the state of the fingers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277795/3-finger-gripper-model-for-moveit/gazebo?/) by [JuanTelo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32449/juantelo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2017-12-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-10**:
@JuanTelo: please don't post answers unless you are *answering* your own question.

If you want to update us on your progress, *edit* your original question with the new information.

For interacting directly with other posters, use comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Juan,

I've recently been working with a 3-finger gripper, and I've used the Smart Grasping simulation provided by Shadow Robot, which provides a 3-finger gripper mounted on an UR10 arm. The repo for this simulation is here: https://github.com/shadow-robot/smart_grasping_sandbox

I just wanted the 3-finger gripper in my simulation, so I did a couple of basic modifications to the URDF in order to have it. What I basically did was:

1. Remove from the model.urdf file all the stuff related to the UR arm.
2. Add some basic URDF code in order to have a platform where I place the gripper.
3. Remove from the launch file all the controllers related to the arm, and make sure that is taking my new URDF file, which contains only the hand data.

I have created this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dnjP0z333-k&t=2s) showing the whole process, which really just takes like 5 minutes.

Hope this helps you!

---

Originally posted by [Alberto E.](https://answers.ros.org/users/31003/alberto-e./) with karma: 356 on 2017-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2